# Write a SQL query to calculate the Total using a value in one columns and next/previous value in other column

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have this table where I know the sales and total on a particular date. I have sales data for the other dates but the Total is unknown. I need to fill in the previous/later Total using the Sales columns.

| Date | Sales | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-01 | 100 | NA |
| 2019-01-02 | 200 | 1000 |
| 2019-01-03 | -150 | NA |
| 2019-01-04 | 300 | NA |

Desired output:

| Date | Sales | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-12-31 | -200 | 700 : 800 -(100) or 1000 - (200+100) |
| 2019-01-01 | 100 | 800 : 1000 - 200 |
| 2019-01-02 | 200 | 1000 : This total is known |
| 2019-01-03 | -150 | 850 :1000+ (-150) |
| 2019-01-04 | 300 | 1150 :850+ 300 or 1000 + (-150 + 300) |

```
CREATE TABLE SALES (DATE DATE, SALES INT, TOTAL INT);
INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES
('2018-12-31', -200, NULL)
('2019-01-01', 100, NULL),
('2019-01-02', 200, 1000),
('2019-01-03',150, NULL),
('2019-01-04', 300, NULL
```

Query can be divided into two parts before and after known. Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: your numbers come out of nowhere

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: your first table starts with 2019-01-01 qand your result table with the 2018-12-31, your first total lisst 1000 that is nowhere and the -200  also not in the source table, like i said out if nowhere

Comment: This has been already answered. Question was more of working backwards and forwards from the known row which is the 2nd row in the 1st table. Whats prior to that doesnt matter. I added an additional row in the 2nd table for calculation reference only.

Comment: and how can we now if it is a negative like 2019-01-03 or positive like 2019-01-04

Answer (score 0):

```
with data as (
    select "Date" as Dt, Sales,
        min(case when Total is not null then "Date" end) over () as KnownDt,
        min(Total) over () as KnownTot
    from SALES
)
select Dt, Sales,
    KnownTot
        - coalesce(sum(case when Dt <= KnownDt then Sales end) over (order by Dt desc rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding), 0)
        + sum(case when Dt  > KnownDt then Sales else 0 end) over (order by Dt asc) as Total
from data;
```

First pull out the known values. Then add/subtract running sales totals relative to the known date.

You can get the nice symmetry back without a messy `coalesce()` by doing the shift via `lead()` in the earlier step:

```
with data as (
    select "Date" as Dt, Sales,
        lead(Sales) over (order by Dt) as LSales,
        min(case when Total is not null then "Date" end) over () as KnownDt,
        min(Total) over () as KnownTot
    from SALES
)
select Dt, Sales,
    KnownTot
        - sum(case when Dt < KnownDt then LSales else 0 end) over (order by Dt desc)
        + sum(case when Dt > KnownDt then  Sales else 0 end) over (order by Dt asc) as Total
from data;
```

Comment: Unfortunately. This doesn't work. This gives a total column of all Nulls, except the known row

Comment: I had just been in the shower and realized I needed the sums to explicitly evaluate to zero. I also fixed the staggered total projecting backward.

Comment: Thank you, this works fine for the forward cases, works for backward cases as well, except the very 1st case before the knowndt, should be 1200 (1000 +200).

Comment: The latest edit works perfectly. Thank you so much